# Notify someone by email if FileVault Safari-Only Guest User logs in

Tags: email, command-line, filevault, launchd, guest-account

This question is related to questions 154363 and 144801 (I can't link to them b/c I don't have the reputation and need my two link limit below), but they don't quite answer what I need.

Please note that I also asked this question on the Apple Support Forums [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30680020#30680020), but I realized that it may not be the right place to address this question and I'm not sure that it can be migrated here. If the question can be migrated and this a cross-post, I apologize. Let me know which community may be better suited to address this question, and I'll contact the Apple Support community to request it be migrated if necessary, and this can be closed.

Here's the summary: I have an early-2015 Macbook Pro with Yosemite (10.10.5). It has FileVault enabled, and so it has the Safari-Only Guest User. I'm familiar with the terminal, and just started learning about launchd and daemons, but have little experience with the innards of Mac OS X or AppleScript.

I need to be able to be notified by email or other means if someone logs into the Safari-Only guest user account. I found an old forum discussing installing Prey on the Safari-Only guest user account [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/prey-security/vBv3BGI8Qeg/SPZoZgW1LicJ), and I saw this as a good lead toward the solution. I also found a tutorial to send an email using a launchd daemon on Apple Discussion forums (thread #2523408). However, to put these together, it seems to me that there would require other dependencies to make it possible to send an email on the Guest User, or that I otherwise would need to write an applescript or something to do the notifying through Safari.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks